# Calculate total price of items that fit within weight and size limits of a suitcase

Tags: javascript

A salesperson who walks door to door to sell goods carries a suitcase with him. Each morning he packs his suitcase with items from his inventory. Each item has a size (cm3), price (Rs) and weight (grams). Write a javascript programme to calculate the total price of the items he can carry in his suitcase without exceeding the max weight and size limits of the suitcase.

> Products list:
>
> Item 01: weight: 10, price: 20, size: 30
> Item 02: weight: 15, price: 25, size: 35
> Item 03: weight: 20, price: 30, size: 40
> Item 04: weight: 25, price: 35, size: 40
>
> Test 01
>
> Inputs: maxWeight = 50, maxSize = 50
>
> Expected Output: Total price: 35
>
> Test 02
>
> Inputs: maxWeight = 30, maxSize = 100
>
> Expected Output: Total price: 50

They have provided this code snippets for me :

```
function getTotalPrice(items, curWeight, curSize, curIndex) {
  return false;
}

const itemList = [
{ weight: 10, price: 20, size: 30 },
{ weight: 15, price: 25, size: 35 },
{ weight: 20, price: 30, size: 40 },
{ weight: 25, price: 35, size: 40 }
];

getTotalPrice(itemList, 50, 50, itemList.length);
```

I wrote this programme but its only reading and give 35 for the first test. It is correct but ot working for test 2. Please help me with this

```
function getTotalPrice(items, curWeight, curSize, curIndex) {
  const maxWeight = curWeight;
  const maxSize = curSize;
  let totalPrice = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];

    if (item.weight <= maxWeight && item.size <= maxSize) {
      totalPrice = item.price;
    }
  }
  console.log(totalPrice);
  return totalPrice;
}

const itemList = [
  { weight: 10, price: 20, size: 30 },
  { weight: 15, price: 25, size: 35 },
  { weight: 20, price: 30, size: 40 },
  { weight: 25, price: 35, size: 40 },
];

getTotalPrice(itemList, 50, 50, itemList.length);
```

Comment: The issue in your code lies in the line totalPrice = item.price;. This line overwrites the totalPrice with the current item's price in each iteration of the loop, so it only considers the last item in the loop.You should accumulate the prices instead of overwriting the totalPrice.      ` totalPrice += item.price;`

Comment: This is a good time to learn about using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/) so you can step through the code statement by statement, look at the values of the variables as they change, and see what's going on.

Comment: This looks like [Knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/), and that too a 0/1 Knapsack. I can solve it, but it would be better if you go through this algorithm and answer the question yourself. You will learn this new algorithm, and an optimized way to solve it.

Comment: Yes indeed i used totalPrice += item.price but it return sum(price)  of all the items in the array.